# Is there a way to get sql to output information arranged by month while showing a percentage for each month?

Tags: sql, t-sql

This outputs two columns. First is number of incidents, second is a 1 or 0 for breached or not breached. I'm trying to see if there's a way to show this data arranged by month with a percentage of breached vs not breached.

```
SELECT TOP 5000


[incidents] = Count(task_sla.dv_sla),
task_sla.has_breached,
resolved_at

FROM 

incident
left join task_sla
on incident.number = task_sla.dv_task

WHERE 

dv_task like 'INC%'
and dv_sla like 'Resolution%'

GROUP BY
task_sla.has_breached,
resolved_at
```

Comment: And where is the date in the data?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: I added a new field to pull date/ time from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(i.date), MONTH(i.date), 
       COUNT(*) as num_incidents,
       AVG(CASE WHEN t.has_breached = 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as ratio_breached
FROM incident i left join
     task_sla t
     on i.number = t.dv_task and
        t.dv_task like 'INC%' 
WHERE ?.dv_sla like 'Resolution%'
GROUP BY YEAR(i.date), MONTH(i.date)
ORDER BY YEAR(i.date), MONTH(i.date);
```

Comment: This was perfect, thank you. I subbed date for the date the incident was resolved at and it looks great.